# Settings dialog window font size not console font size in Comemu

Tags: windows-10, conemu, display-settings, high-dpi

Is it possible to set the font size in the settings window of Conemu (not the different tasks/console windows)?  Have been searching, but only sizes for consoles have been returned.  Thanks!

Comment: dialog fonts are generally a windows setting.

Comment: Have you even opened the settings dialog?

Comment: Have I even opened the settings dialog?  Yes, how else would I know the fonts within it are too small?  Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Unless you show the screenshot of the dialog with "too small" fonts, nobody can understand you question...